# Number Format: 1.0 = "0000100000"

Tags: ms-access

I have a task to deliver a numeric/decimal value as part of a fixed length text file.  These values will take the following form:

10 chars, w/last 5 chars representing the decimal portion of the string.  These will all be positive numbers.

A few examples:

0.123 = "0000012300"
1.0 = "0000100000"
123.456 = "0012345600"
234 = "0023400000"

The numeric data resides in an Access database formatted as numbers (double).

My current thought is:

1. Retain the orignal numeric data in one table
2. Convert to TEXT strings via query, save to a second table
3. Export to a fixed width flat file using MSAccess export function

Can anyone suggest a reasonable approach to produce the necessary 10 character TEXT conversion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps just multiply by 100000 and format?

```
Format(x * 100000, "0000000000")
```

Comment: Thanks @Gord!   Yep, came to post this same approach.  Simple!